# How to center the text in table with image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to move the text that i circle with red to center. Does anyone know how to do it?. The text and image in a table. Unfortunately, the position of the text not in center.

[image]

Comment: try tihs add new tr  and set textAlign center ?? 
or send code please

Comment: The code is like this. <table> <tr><td>image</td><td>text</td></tr></table> and i want the text in center not at the bottom just like the picture i post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
    <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/2000px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="200"7>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="center">
           Test
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: i just try that but its not work for me. My code is like this.



 <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/2000px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="200"7>
          </td>
<td align="center">Test</td>
         </tr>
        </table>

Comment: this is true code. I dont know  why didnt work.
Can u send all code on page ? Update question pls.

Comment: <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="text" align="center" ><asp:Label ID="terminal" runat="server"/></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="text" align="center"><asp:Label ID="jigCodeTer" runat="server" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="text"><asp:Image ID="picTer" runat="server" Height="200" Width="200" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="text" align="center"><asp:Label ID="jigCodeRet" runat="server" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="text"><asp:Image ID="PicRet" runat="server" Height="200" Width="200" /></td>
        </tr>

Comment: add align : center  in css text class

Comment: i also try that but the result is same. it will center the text but at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I just find a solution. I just add this to my css.

```
.td {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
```

}